# Upload artifacts to aws from circle ci

Tags: amazon-s3, continuous-integration, circleci

I have created this yam file to create a binary image for my iot board with circle ci..

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  python: circleci/python@1.4.0

jobs:
  build:
    executor: python/default
    steps:
      - checkout # checkout source code to working directory
      - run:
          name: Install PlatformIO
          command: pip install --upgrade platformio
      - run:
          name: Compile Project
          command: pio run
      - run:
          name: Creating Dummy Artifacts
          command: |
            cd .pio/build/esp32dev
            echo "firmare.bin" > /tmp/art-1;
            mkdir /tmp/artifacts;
            echo "my artifact files in a dir" > /tmp/artifacts/art-2;
      - store_artifacts:
          path: /tmp/art-1
          destination: artifact-file
      - store_artifacts:
          path: /tmp/artifacts

workflows:
  main:
    jobs:
      - build
```

I would like to store the artifact the firmware.bin in a bucket in aws...
Do you know how to do it or a similar example that I can check and modify ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I guess the simple option is to use [CircleCI's `circleci/aws-s3` orb](https://circleci.com/developer/orbs/orb/circleci/aws-s3).

Comment: hi @yaningo.. but using the orb you mentioned still I can use the orb of python for compiling the project? Can I use 2 orbs in the yaml file ? Thanks a lot

Comment: You can indeed. What you'll be using from the `aws-s3` orb are commands, so they can be included in the existing job. You simply need to reference the `circleci/aws-s3` orb along with the `circleci/python` one. There's no limit on the number of orbs you can reference in your `config.yml`.

Comment: hi @yaningo.. the idea you daid it is clear... I hope to be able to do it... thanks